# Load jQuery dynamically and use it

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to correctly load jQuery library if it is not loaded yet?

somepage.html:

```
<script src="http://example.com/js/widget_init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
    console.log('ERROR: NOT LOADED');
  }
  else{
    console.log('OK');
  }

</script>
```

The script 'widget_init.js' should load jQuery if it is not loaded yet.

I have this script 'widget_init.js':

```
function load_script_jquery(){
  if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
    var jq = document.createElement('script'); jq.type = 'text/javascript';
    jq.src = '/path/to/js/jquery.min.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
  } 
  else {

  }

}

load_script_jquery();

// some other code
```

The problem is that it doesn't wait for jQuery to be loaded and it shows error like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
    console.log('ERROR: NOT LOADED');  // NOT LOADED
  }
  else{
    console.log('OK'); // NEVER GOES HERE
  }

</script>
```

I tried this also without any effect:

```
document.write('<script src="/path/to/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"><\/script>');
```

How to wait until jQuery is loaded so I can use it ?

Comment: JS is sync and interrupter. So It read and wait line by line only

Comment: The  `document.write` theoretically should work as this will block the execution of the following script. Might be a problem with the `<\/script>`, but this is a very bad solution anyway. It would be better to add a listen for the `load` even of the script, and put the following code into a function that will be called by the load callback.

Comment: I tried this in my script: document.write('<script src="/path/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');

if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {   console.log('BAD'); } 
else {  console.log('OK');}
It says "BAD".

Answer (score 2):

Your code to append the jQuery script will be appended **after** your `<script>` snippet that checks for it. That's how `.appendChild` works

> The Node.appendChild() method adds a node to the **end** of the list of children of a specified parent node

*Source:* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild (emphasis mine)

Here are two options to solve this:

**If you can insert HTML on the page**

You can use this snippet from the [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/index.html#L26). It will check if another script has already loaded jQuery, and if not, will load it inline.

`<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>`

Just drop it in your head or body tag before the script that depends on it.

**If you need to dynamically load it in the Javascript source**

Follow the instructions in [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/dynamically-load-jquery-library-javascript/)

```
(function () {

    function loadScript(url, callback) {

        var script = document.createElement("script")
        script.type = "text/javascript";

        if (script.readyState) { //IE
            script.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (script.readyState == "loaded" || script.readyState == "complete") {
                    script.onreadystatechange = null;
                    callback();
                }
            };
        } else { //Others
            script.onload = function () {
                callback();
            };
        }

        script.src = url;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    }

    loadScript("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function () {

         //jQuery loaded
         console.log('jquery loaded');

    });


})();
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I placed this if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
    console.log('BAD - not loaded');
}   in the script AFTER your code and it says 'BAD - not loaded'. Seems like I have to place my code in the callback function.

Comment: Yeah, if it's not working by placing things in order, that callback function should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You just need callback function, after loading jquery secessfully:

```
var loadJS = function(url, cb) {
        var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
        script_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        script_tag.setAttribute("src",
            url);
        if (script_tag.readyState) {
            script_tag.onreadystatechange = function() { // For old versions of IE
                if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
                    cb();//calling callback
                }
            };
        } else { // Other browsers
            script_tag.onload = cb;//calling callback function
        }
        (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
    };
```

And simply call this function with jquery library path and callback function reference:

```
loadJS(hostUrl + "/js/libraries/jquery.js", callback);
```